# how to point spring boot application to external jar's logback.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, logback

I have created one spring boot application having logback implementation. After that I have created jar and imported that jar in another spring boot application via nexus repository. In my current spring boot application how can I point `logback.xml` from my imported jar which is located at `\\BOOT-INF\\classes\\logback.xml` inside jar ?

I have tried below list of configuration in `application.properties`:

```
-logging.config=logback.xml
-logging.config=file:\\BOOT-INF\\classes\\logback.xml
-logging.config=classpath:logback.xml
```

Could anyone give me hint or exact configuration needed in my spring boot application, so my current application can generate logs based on parent logback.xml configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below configuration

```
- java -jar -Dlog4j.configuration="file:d:\log4j.xml" myjar.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try config based on your project structure
java -Dlogging.file=target/my_logfile.log -jar spring_boot_app.jar

Comment: The question is on using external jar's logback.xml. The answer doesn't have any references to it. Please correct it.